# postgresql selecting highest values

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I have the following student table:

```
Student_Name Student_RollNo Student_Marks1 Student_Marks2
Andrew       10             90.9           9.2
Blake        2              78.2           100
Fisher       1              69.2           89
Alex         1              98.8           82.1
```

My query:

```
select * 
from Student
order by (Student_Marks1+Student_Marks2) limit 1;
```

i.e. I want to retrieve the student details of Student with the highest marks. Here highest marks is a function which is a summation of Student_Marks1 and Student_Marks2. Now I am curious to know which algorithm does postgresql (or mysql) uses for performing this ranking?

i.e does postgresql apply ORDER BY first and then LIMIT; OR does it apply LIMIT first and then ORDER BY; or does it use an algorithm which applies ORDER BY and LIMIT together

Comment: natural ordering, from lowest to highest.  If a numeric type column, then sorted based on numeric value.  If text column, sorted based on collation of character set being used for column (essentially alphabetically).  If you want the largest first, then order descending: `order by Student_Marks desc`

Comment: @DBug Yes you are very correct but what if I want to order based on multiple attributes (or columns). Then I am curious to know which ranking algorithm does postgresql use to perform this ranking

Comment: You're asking how ORDER BY works?

Comment: @muistooshort Yes I am asking how ORDER BY and STOP AFTER together work in postgresql. I mean does postgresql uses ORDER BY first and then STOP AFTER or is it the vice versa or does postgresql use both of them together?

Comment: Postgres _has_ to apply the `order by` first, otherwise it couldn't determine what the "first row" is. As for the actual sorting, I think Postgres uses a merge sort. Check the execution plan using `explain (analyze, verbose)` I think it will tell you.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name One can check the execution plan for just a limited number of queries :) But I wanted to know in general, how does postgresql do ranking? -- I mean does it have any specialized algorithm to do ranking?

Comment: Postgres must `order by` first, then `limit` the result afterwards. No "special" ranking algorithm, read http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-order.html and then for limit http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/queries-limit.html on ranking (a different) topic see http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/functions-window.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally the algorithm is very simple:

1. Retrieve rows from `Student` table
2. Sort the whole resultset from #1 using ORDER BY expressions
3. Apply LIMIT clause (+ offset) to get a portion of rows from ordered resultset obtained from #2

You can read more on LIMIT here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/queries-limit.html

In some cases LIMIT is taken into account during ORDER BY operation (sorting) to speed up the query, especially when some index can be used to eliminate a sort operation.

You can examine how this work looking at explain plans.

Let's say there is an index created on this table:

```
create index student_mark1 on student(student_marks1);
```

This query gives the following explain plan:

```
select * From student
order by student_marks2 
limit 1;

Limit  (cost=5.06..5.06 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=0.088..0.089 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2
  ->  Sort  (cost=5.06..5.57 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.088..0.088 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2
        Sort Key: student.student_marks2
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on public.student  (cost=0.00..4.04 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.007..0.021 rows=204 loops=1)
              Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2
```

You need to read this plan from bottom to up.

The first operation is `Seq scan` - it means that the all rows are read from disk (the whole table - see `actual rows = 204`).

Then the sort operation is performed (ORDER BY). And the last operation is LIMIT 1 (at the top of the plan)

Compare the above plan to this query:

```
select * From student
order by student_marks1 
limit 1;

Limit  (cost=0.14..0.24 rows=1 width=178) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=1)
  Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2
  ->  Index Scan using student_mark1 on public.student  (cost=0.14..19.20 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.009..0.009 rows=1 loops=1)
        Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2
```

Here the sorting phase is skipped, since we can use the index to retrieve rows in required order (`ORDER BY student_marks1 => INDEX ON Student( student_marks1 )`).

Please take notice of `Actual rows = 1` in the bottom-most operation: `Index scan'.

This means, that PostgreSQL doesn't scan the whole index, but retrieves only 1 (first) row from the index, because it knows, than the query has LIMIT 1 clause. (One sometimes says that PostgreSQL "pushed down" limit 1 clause to the index scan operation and used it to reduce a number of scanned entries in the index).

More on using indices to speed up ORDER BY you can find here: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/indexes-ordering.html

In case the query in your question, the `ORDER BY` clause contains an expression `Student_Marks1+Student_Marks2`, not a simple columns. An explain plan for this query looks like this:

```
select *
From student
order by student_marks1 + student_marks2 
limit 2;

Limit  (cost=7.10..7.11 rows=2 width=178) (actual time=0.207..0.207 rows=2 loops=1)
  Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2, (((student_marks1)::numeric + student_marks2))
  ->  Sort  (cost=7.10..7.61 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.205..0.205 rows=2 loops=1)
        Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2, (((student_marks1)::numeric + student_marks2))
        Sort Key: (((student.student_marks1)::numeric + student.student_marks2))
        Sort Method: top-N heapsort  Memory: 25kB
        ->  Seq Scan on public.student  (cost=0.00..5.06 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.019..0.107 rows=204 loops=1)
              Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2, ((student_marks1)::numeric + student_marks2)
```

But you can still speed up this query creating a `function based index`, in this way:

```
create index student_mark12 on student( ( student_marks1 + student_marks2) );
```

After creating the index, we have now:

```
Limit  (cost=0.14..0.34 rows=2 width=178) (actual time=0.044..0.047 rows=2 loops=1)
  Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2, (((student_marks1)::numeric + student_marks2))
  ->  Index Scan using student_mark12 on public.student  (cost=0.14..20.22 rows=204 width=178) (actual time=0.043..0.046 rows=2 loops=1)
        Output: student_name, student_rollno, student_marks1, student_marks2, ((student_marks1)::numeric + student_marks2)
```

Notice that Postgre uses the index in this case, and retrieves only 2 entries from it (actual rows = 2) according to `LIMIT 2`  clause.

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL uses the default B-tree operator class to determine the sort ordering within an ORDER BY expression (ASC as the default using < to sort smaller first, DESC using > to get larger).

As for your comment question about multiple attributes, it uses ORDER BY in sequence based on your entry of the sort fields.

Comment: I am afraid...but how does it use ORDER BY in sequence on 2 attributes i.e. marks1 and marks2. As it needs to sort on the summation of marks1 and marks2 and then use limit i.e. retrieve the highest record

Comment: Also can you please refer me to some document from which I can read more about the same.